# Adding Nodes to a BinarySearchTree

Tags: java

I ran into problem and can't figure it out why my nodes are not being added to a Binary Tree. I feel like it sets the node and than in the next loop it resets it.

`E` is a `Customer` object

`T` is a `LinkedList`, list of integers.

I'm not sure if I have to implement the Interface parent also.
I can see in console that it always sets nodes to the right. 
Where's the error in my code?

Update:
If I replace in the add method

```
    BinaryNode<E, T> parent =  new BinaryNode<>() ;
```

with

```
Parent<E, T> parent = this;
```

Then it seems like its going into while loop and compares, I can see println statements in a console. But then I get an error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    teama.tree.BinaryNode cannot be cast to teama.tree.Parent
    at teama.tree.BinarySearchTree.add(BinarySearchTree.java:32)
    at teama.tree.TestBtree.main(TestBtree.java:44)
```

and this code is highlighted and offering cast it to a BinaryNode:

```
    parent = (Parent<E, T>) node;
```

If I remove the cast from it

```
    parent =  node;
```

then it highlight the `node` with the red underline and offers it to cast back.
Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Here's the code:

```
public class BinaryNode<E, T> {

    /** The item associated with this node. */
    private E item;
    private T item2;

    /** The node at the root of the left subtree. */
    private BinaryNode<E, T> left;

    /** The node at the root of the right subtree. */
    private BinaryNode<E, T> right;

    public BinaryNode() {

    }

    /** Put item in a leaf node. */
    public BinaryNode(E item, T item2) {
        this.item = item;
        this.item2 = item2;

    public void setChild(int direction, BinaryNode<E, T> child) {
        if (direction < 0) {
            System.out.println("set Left");
            left = child;
        } else {
            System.out.println("set Right");
            right = child;
        }
    }
```

Here's `BinaryTree` class

```
public class BinarySearchTree <E extends Comparable<E>, T> 
    implements Parent<E, T>, Set<E> {
 {

    /** Root node. */
    private BinaryNode<E, T> root;

    /** A BinarySearchTree is initially empty. */
    public BinarySearchTree() {
       root = null;
    }
```

Here I had to replace `Parent<E,T>` with the `BinaryNode<E, T>`, because nodes below were offered to cast by Eclipse, mismatch type.

```
public void add(E target, T list) {
    // Here I replaced Parent<E> parent = this;  
    //  with BinaryNode<E, T> parent =  new BinaryNode<>()
    BinaryNode<E, T> parent =  new BinaryNode<>() ;
    BinaryNode<E, T> node = root;
    int comparison = 0;
    while (node != null) {
        System.out.println("While loop:");
        comparison = target.compareTo(node.getItem());
        System.out.println("Comparison=" + comparison);
        if (comparison < 0) {     // Go left
            System.out.println("Go Left");
            parent = node;
            node = node.getLeft();
        } else if (comparison == 0) {
            // It's already here
            return;
        } else {
            // Go right
            System.out.println("Go Right");
            parent = node;
            node = node.getRight();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("from add method: " + target +" list=" + list);
    // BinaryNode<E, T> newNode = new BinaryNode<E, T>(target, list);
    // newNode.setChild(comparison, newNode);
    parent.setChild(comparison, new BinaryNode<E, T>(target, list));
}
```

And `Parent` interface:

```
public interface Parent<E, T> {

    /**
    * Return the left child if direction < 0, or the right child
    * otherwise.
    */
    public BinaryNode<E, T> getChild(int direction);

    /**
    * Replace the specified child of this parent with the new child.
    * If direction < 0, replace the left child.  Otherwise, replace
    * the right child.
    */
    public void setChild(int direction, BinaryNode<E, T> child);
```

Comment: 1. Your indentation is terrible.  Do you seriously expect people to read that?  How are they supposed to help you if they can't read the code?  2.  Insertion into a binary tree is often recursive and I don't see a call to `add()` in your `add()` procedure.  Something very off there.

Comment: @markspace 1. I fixed indentation 2. Like this `Parent<E> parent = this;`?

Comment: 1. Thank you!  2.  Hmm, no.  It's been a while since I've written a non-recursive tree walk but I'm pretty sure that tracking only one parent won't work.  You need to make your own stack and track each node at which there might be a branch in the walk.  3. If you're new at this, recursion is much easier.  Get that working first, then try an non-recursive walk.

Comment: @markspace Unfortunately I have to work with this code as a part of the assignment. I'll definitely look into recursion also. Thanks!

Comment: You have to work with this code?  You didn't write that method yourself?  Or your instructor told you to write it this way?  If that latter, you probably should be building a chain of parent objects, and you have just one.  Keep making `new Parent()` where you decide to go left or right, so you can follow the chain back up to a decision point if needed.  This is a really weird and unnatural way to write a non-recursive walk though.

Comment: @markspace That's right, I didn't write the method myself. It's from the school book.

Comment: This is a weird method.  I think you may have mis-copied.  What does the `T list` parameter do?

Comment: @markspace The `T list` is a list of Integers for every Customer object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it resolved. In my BinaryNode class I haven't implemented interface parent, and that's why it was giving me mismatch error type. After I added `implements Parent<E>` to `public class BinaryNode<E, T>` it works fine now.